# Shooting a ball from the middle of the camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

I;m trying to make the first person character to shoot a ball from the middle of the camera,
but it's just not working.
Here is the first person character's script: 
public Rigidbody ball;

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")) {
        Instantiate(ball,transform.position+new Vector3(0,1,0),transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

and here is the ball's script :

```
public float speed=20;
Vector3 direction;
void Start () {
    direction = Camera.main.transform.forward;
}
void Update () {

    transform.Translate(direction *Time.deltaTime*speed);
    Destroy(gameObject,3);

}
```

The ball is prefab.The problem is that the ball is not coming from the center of the camera.
I dont understand why its not working.
Anyone can help me?
Thank you!

Comment: the ball is comming from where then?

Comment: from around the first person character, not from the center.

Comment: probably bc of this `transform.position+new Vector3(0,1,0)`?

Comment: no, this is just to raise the starting point of the ball.

Comment: the ball fly correctly with the position and direction? the problem is just that it appear around the camera instead in the center? around where.. randomly?

Comment: not randomly, whenever i'm at specific direction it shoot the ball to a specific point.

Comment: move `Destroy(gameObject,3);` to the `Start` method. Change `transform.Translate(direction *Time.deltaTime*speed);` to `transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime*speed);`. Works?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your script does not work is the wrong position in Instantiate function, because you **shouldn't assume that that player is facing into positive Y axis direction**.

Code of instantiation should look like this:

```
Instantiate(ball,transform.position + transform.forward*(distance_from_camera),transform.rotation);
```

We set position to players transform.position increased by "forward" vector (it indicates in which direction object is facing), multiplying this value by distance in which instantiated object will appear.

Edit: 1. In ball script the direction should be just transform.forward.
2. Instantiated ball should have forward direction equal to camera's forward. To achieve this you have to set the ball to be child of camera, the change localRotation to (0, 0, 0). After it "unchild" the ball, so it won't have  a parent.

Comment: I dont understand. i removed the +new Vector3(0,1,0)
and its still not working
I tried using your code and it didnt work either

Comment: its still going to different directions

Comment: it is attached to the camera. But its not working.
when i rotate the camera to the left the ball suddenly moves too much to the left.thats happen with the right direction too.
when the game is just starting and the camera is not rotated ecreything works fine

Answer (score 0):

You were so close! you just needed to instantiate it at the *cameras* position!

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")) {
        Instantiate(ball,Camera.main.transform.position,transform.rotation);
    }
}
```